# In Numbers, how can I sum only if adjacent cell is certain value?

Tags: numbers, iwork

In excel, as shown [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2515-excel-sumif-adjacent-cell-equals-is-blank-contains-text.html), it is possible to find and sum only cells with have a specific value next to them.

[image: =SUM(IF(A4:E10=A13, B4:F10, 0))]

Is there a way to do a similar thing in numbers?

Specifically, I have a very long table like this:

```
Type of Job | Amount Earned
------------+--------------
Labour      | 10
Labour      | 15
Office      | 27
Labour      | 10
Tutoring    | 20
Labour      | 5
Office      | 24
Tutoring    | 20
```

And I'd like to find out how much money I've made from jobs of type `Labour`, `Office` and `Tutoring` separately. I can't just sum the `Amount Earned` column, because that would only give me the total of *all* Job Types, instead I want their totals separately.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you can use the `SUMIF` function to accomplish this:

```
SUMIF(test-range, condition, sum-range)
```